# Importing third party library in AnglularJS with System.js

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, two.js

In this angular2 [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iUAP9sMhldO88Mwl3rNN?p=preview), I am trying to import two.js (third party lib) and bootstrap it into my application. Using system.config.js, I added the following lines among the mappings and packages vars :

```
  var map = {
        ...othermappings
       'two.js' : 'https://npmcdn.com/two.js@0.6.0/src'
     };
 var packages = {
         ...otherpackages
       'two.js': { main: 'two.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
   }
```

Inside main.ts, If I uncomment the following line:

```
import {Two} from 'two.js';
```

and also added :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...others,
    //Two
 ])
```

I get the follwoing error:

```
(index):20 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFunction' of undefined(…)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs on the line:

```
hasEventListeners: _.isFunction(root.addEventListener),
```

As you can see `isFunction` is a method of `_` object. It's underscore.

From the Two.js [documentation](https://jonobr1.github.io/two.js/):

> N.B. Two.js requires Underscore.js and Backbone.js Events. If you're
>   already loading these files elsewhere then you can build the project
>   yourself and get the file size even smaller.

This way, **first step** is to load underscore and backbone [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQxfjVle7rKO8SutBLcQ?p=preview)

See *index.html*

```
<!-- Two.js dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

**Second step** is to change your import statement from

```
import {Two} from 'two.js';
```

to

```
import * as Two  from 'two.js'
```

After that `Two` will be your desired function.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dHN8vTQ4wUTfD9kugf2q?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for the reply. If you uncomment line 17 in main.ts where:                     "//Two"  the plunk does not load and passes the error I am referring to.

Comment: I've updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/dHN8vTQ4wUTfD9kugf2q?p=preview. But i think that you need't be used two.js as a provider. You can just use it like `new Two` where you want

Comment: thanks for the update. I am exactly challenged by the inclusion of a third party lib with angular2, this is why I am trying to import and bootstrap two.js as a provider.